# Git seems to 'lose' a commit

Tags: git

Is it possible for git to have a commit on master  and, perhaps due to a developer improperly resolving a conflict, actually 'lose' the commit? (*Edit*: By "lose the commit", I mean not only lose the changes, but actually lose all record that the commit ever happened.)

Scenario: A week or two ago there was a bugfix on our master branch that we know was pushed to our live server and worked.  Today, the bugfix disappeared from live.  I remembered resolving a recent conflict in that file, but when I went to look for the fix in our git repo, I could find no trace of it on the master branch or any other branches that I suspect may have touched the file.  I checked the file's git history and git blame but saw no commits recent enough to have been the bugfix.  How is this possible?

Comment: someone could have reset the branch to the previous commit and forced pushed that state to the repo. However, by its decentralized nature, git clones that had fetched that commit will still have it

Comment: Thanks, njzk2.  I'm dubious our team has done something like that in the recent past, but I suppose it is plausible.  We did perform a large merge yesterday, though.  Is there any way that merging in a topic branch, especially a large branch with lots of merges down from master, could effectively reset the master branch?

Comment: Anything is possible in a merge. If you know, where the problem is, you could investigate with git log, diff and blame.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever this has happened to me, it has always been a merge.

This exact scenario happened to me once (I think many times, though I wasn't perfectly able to prove it except once).

Here is what happened:

1. Someone branches from master to their own branch, called `feature/foo`.
2. I make a fix in the master branch.
3. They complete their work in `feature/foo`, and merge it into master like 
   this:

   ```
   # git status
   On branch feature/foo
   # git checkout master
   # git merge feature/foo --theirs
   ```

They used `--theirs` because 98% of the time that is appropriate -- it says whenever they made a change and it conflicts with master, adopt the code from their branch. But they never merged master into their feature branch before they merged back into master, so **their branch did not have my fix.** The `--theirs` ensures that their un-fixed code overwrote my fixed code, and my change magically disappeared.

I was able to detect this via looking at the magically un-fixed lines via `git annotate`. I checked out commit after commit, using git annotate and looking at the lines in question until I found out which commit was the last to have my fix in it and which commit didn't have my fix anymore. I found that my fix disappeared during just such a merge.

Prior to this incident I've had normal merges do the same thing, except it happened in mercurial instead of git. The developer doesn't merge master into their feature branch, and when they merged their fix back into master after I made the fix, my fix disappeared.

After this incident, I called a meeting just so I could educate fellow developers about this problem and let them know that merges should be handled with care.

Comment: That sounds about like our scenario, but I can't seem to get what happens in the conflict resolution.  I can see why the _lines of code_ would be missing in a poorly resolved conflict, but why is the actual _commit_ missing?  Shouldn't master at least keep a record that the commit happened, even if the changes are gone?

Comment: My coworker has an interesting theory; he's wondering if Git discards both conflicting commits in favor of the committed resolution.  This seems plausible to me -- I may go dig around in Git documentation to find out for sure.

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I'd like to hear the results. This is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not find the commit in the git history, this seems like if someone did `git push --force` to the remote.

Locally it can happen when you do `git reset --hard`.

**Check `git reflog` for a list of recent operations**. First column is a list of SHA1s of HEADs sorted by time, newest first. This may help you find the lost commit.