# Merging when master is behind

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

So I have branchA, branchB, and master. branchB was many commits behind master. I merged branchB into branchA and then branchA into master. This successfully merged the feature I added in branchA. However, since branchB was so much behind, it removed other coworkers' feature that were already merged into master. We ended up reverting branchA.

My question is how do I get branchA's changes without deleting other features.

Comment: I would recommend using `git rebase -i <some_commit_to_start_from>` The `-i` flag allows for interactive choices for each commit.

Comment: If a and b were both off matter it's often easier to bring them up to date with master first.

Comment: So would I rebase B to master first and then remerge that back into A?

Comment: I'm reading this: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history

And I'm kind of confused on how to do an interactive rebase. Correct me if I'm wrong, but would I just do `git rebase -i <CommitNumberOfBintoA> ` to drop B and leave everything commited into A after B? Then Update B and remerge B?

Comment: "since branchB was so much behind, it removed other coworkers' feature that were already merged into master" - could you clarify this? Merging even old branch should not revert anything. It would rather create a conflict which, with correct resolution, would preserve the feature

Comment: I was able to fix it with the interactive rebase. I'm still not sure how this happened. I looked at my command line history and it looked like after I merged B into A I pulled from the remote master. Then before I merged A into Master I also did another pull to make sure it was up to date. Could it be that B was pending a pull request on BitBucket and it somehow got squashed into A?

Comment: Pull requests do not differ in this respect from usual branches and merges. If you use to use some keys for "automatic" conflict resolution, this [could happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971114/2303202) (I'd say it eventually will happen, and not agree with the "98% appropriate" remark there). Also, if you use [git-rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) it could be resolved wrongly once, and then it slipped through when in same repository the real merge was done. If you take those things under control, mergin older branches should not cause anything bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can update your branches by rebasing the master into your branch

Comment: Is that different than doing a `git pull origin master` from inside my branch? I did that and it updated my branch with the correct master but wiped out my feature.

Comment: So I checked out my branchA and did `git rebase master` and it wiped out the feature still.